# Masking input value after showing a few characters

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an form `input[type=text]` that I would only like to show the first few characters, followed by the corresponding number of asterisks. For instance, if the value was `banana`, the input would display `ban***` but would still submit `banana`.

A password field isn't the solution because I want to show some number of characters from the actual value.

I was thinking of saving the value in a data attribute and adding/remove on keydown, updating to asterisks on blur, and changing the value on submit but worry this could get messy. I'm using jQuery so I'm open to any plugins that may be out there as well.

Comment: How to type input into this field? If I have the cursor at possition 5 like this: `banan|a` it would display `ban**|*` ? And what would happen if i press the key `R`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I've keep a track of original text, and inside the edit I change chars after 3 into password char.

The proper password is then stored inside a data attribute `data-orig`, that you can then read when you submit data.

```js
const i = $("input");

i.on("input", function () {
  const $t = $(this);
  const orig = $t.attr("data-orig") || "";  
  const v = $t.val().split("");
  for (l = 1; l < orig.length && l < v.length; l += 1) {
    v[l] = orig[l];
  }
  $t.attr("data-orig", v.join(""));
  for (l = 3; l < v.length; l += 1) {
    v[l] = "●";
  }
  $t.val(v.join(""));  
});

$("button").on("click", function () {
  console.log(i.attr("data-orig"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text">

<button>Get pwd</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a hidden input field to store the real value and add a `onchange`-listener to it. So when it gets an Update the visible filed will get the update to. This function have to be triggerd `onLoad` to

HTML

```
<input type="hidden" name="realField" value="banana" onChange="update()">
<input type="text" readonly="readonly">
```

JS

```
function update(){
  var text = $('input[name=realField]').val();
  var s = '';
  for(var i=3; i<text.length; ++i){
    s+='*';
  }
  text = text.substr(0, Math.min(text.length, 3)) + s;
  $('input[name=realField] + input').val(text);
}
```